# Mode in each row closest to first index - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of numbers and I want to find the mode of each row, however I want to use the item closest to index 1 if there are multiple modes (built in function just uses the smallest value)

for example:

```
% The 2 takes mode of rows instead of columns
mode([1 2 3 4; 
      4 3 2 1; 
      1 1 2 2; 
      2 2 1 1], 2)
```

actual answer

```
1
1
1
1
```

required answer

```
1
4
1
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) appproach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to take you home -

```
unqA = unique(A)                                       %// Unique values in A
pos = bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(unqA,[3 2 1])) %// positions of unique values in A
count_pos = sum(pos,2)%// Count of occurrences for each unqA in each row of A
max_count = max(count_pos,[],3)  %// Count of max occurances in each row of A

%// Mask pos with the max counts only
mask = bsxfun(@eq,max_count,count_pos)
max_only_pos = bsxfun(@and,mask,pos)

%// Get indices of max counts for in each row & set the invalids to Inf as 
%// we need to use min later on. This min operation would correspond to finding 
%// the indices closest to 1 as per problem requirements.
[valid,max_idx] = max(max_only_pos,[],2)  
max_idx(~valid)=Inf

%// Find min indices & use them as column indices to index into each row of A
out = A(sub2ind(size(A),[1:size(A,1)].',squeeze(min(max_idx,[],3))))
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     2     3     2     4     4     4     5
     5     1     4     4     1     5     5
     2     1     5     1     5     4     5
     5     3     3     2     2     5     4
     4     2     3     1     2     4     1
out =
     4
     5
     5
     5
     4
```

Comment: There we go lol. +1.  My original answer was wrong.  I'm ashamed to have posted it before verifying its authenticity.

Comment: @rayryeng Classical pitfall case when OP posts an input with over-simplified data :)

Comment: @Divakar When i test this with the input i gave it still gives the same as the default mode method.
Also, the sample you gave does not have any cases that would require this custom method.

Comment: @Divakar That works and is well commented, thank you.